# ManyToMany in JPA: how to insert record into join table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 entities in application: Groups and Users, ManyToMany connection between them. When a User is created, it should join several existing Groups.

I saw examples that show how to update 3 tables (2 enities are added, and a new row is created in join table). In my case the Groups table shouldn't be updated, I get org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException because 3 queries are running and one of them is trying to insert a Group that already exists in table.

thanks

Comment: I failed to understand if you actually tried the examples you mentioned, but if the two entities already exists, then Hibernate will only create the link between them, effectively issuing only one SQL (for the join table). If you change the user and/or the group, then more SQLs will be issued, but that's expected. Are you experiencing any specific issue?

Comment: I tried the basic examples, and experienced problems with them: when I create a user and add to it groups, I get ConstraintViolationException because it is trying to insert a group too.

Comment: What are constraints (unique/primary) on your join table? Do you have an extra column with primary key or is unique/primary key a compound of group and user foreign key references.

Comment: In my join table there are no constraints. Constraints are defined in both entity tables.
Now I figured out that if I do a lookup on Service in database, add it to Users, and then persist Users, it works ok.
Probably that's the solution?

Services table have GeneratedValue ID and UniqueConstraint.

Answer (score 0):

A join table like below might solve your problem;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Groups")
public class Group { 

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Group_Users", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<User> users;
```

When a User is created, it should join several existing Groups like this;

**Group_Users**

> **Group_id | User_id**
>
> Group_1   | User_1
>
> Group_2   | User_1
>
> Group_3   | User_1